# pyttsx3 .runAndWait() slows down

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I use the `pyttsx3` library and it slows down the `runAndWait()`.

What is the solution?

PS: [Pyttsx3 runAndWait() method gets stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032027/pyttsx3-runandwait-method-gets-stuck) - I read it, it didn't help

```
def speak(what):
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait() # stop! 
    speak_engine.stop()
speak.start("Hello world!")
```

Comment: I'm writing a voice assistant

Comment: what do you means `slows down`? How you recognize it?

Comment: Stop in the runAndWait(), I put the print command in order to see after which piece of code the program slows down/ stop

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
import pyttsx3
def speak(voice):
  engine = pyttsx3.init()
  rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
  engine.setProperty('rate', rate + 1)
  engine.setProperty('voice', 'com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex')
  engine.say(voice)

  engine.runAndWait()

speak("Hello")
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain to us how and why your code solves the OP's problem as code itself is not always easy to read.

Comment: @Astro Your code doesn't solve the problem, All it does is increase the rate at which it speaks.