# Pyttsx3 "runAndWait" function makes the code stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

I am using python 3.10 and PYTTSX3 2.9 to convert a text into an audio file. I start with a very basic code:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Hello, this is a sample text to speech conversion.")
engine.runAndWait()
engine.say("This is a test to see if the second code works.")
engine.runAndWait()
```

From the code I should hear two texts, but after hearing "Hello, this is a sample text to speech conversion." the code stops and the kernel dies.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I really wish this could be a comment, but I do not have the reputation so here it is:

Have a look at this thread looks like a simular problem to yours. Sounds like you may need to install pyaudio.

[Simular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57181260/13486943)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried it but the problem persists :( I tried the other methods as well but none of them work. Either way thanks for the information, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem good luck with your search!